# Reload updated Table once a column is removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

this is a component that retrieve data from API and generate a table. One button in a column for removing the row opens a Modal.

[image]

For avoiding in first component render to trigger *api.delete request*, an `useRef` set as false in second `useEffect`

Modal's *Delete button* return row info in `deleteHandler` function which successfully trigger *api.delete request* on confirmation,  remove user in backend however table is not reloading.

Once row is removed expected result is triggering *api.get request* and display table now updated and without row removed.

In order to get that result I tried with `const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);` state which introduce another dependency to both `userEffect`

*reload state* effectively reload table data updated however it cause also that *api.delete request* trigger with `const ida` undefined.  Below component script it can find `useEffect` with my tried.

Any hint or possible solution is appreciated

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
... other imports ... 

export default function AllUsers() {
  const api = useApi();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState();
  const [removeUserId, setRemoveUserId] = useState();
  const [ida, setIda] = useState();
  let effectRan = useRef(false);
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await api.get("/admin/users");
      if (response.ok) {
        setUserData(response.body);
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
      }
    })();
  }, [api]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (effectRan.current) {
      // console.log("effect run");

      (async () => {
        const response = await api.delete("/admin/users", {
          ida: ida,
        });
        if (response.ok && response.status === 204) {
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          console.log(response.body.errors);
        }
      })();
    }
    return () => (effectRan.current = true);
  }, [api, ida]);

  const handleEditClick = (e, rowIndex) => {
    // console.log("user/" + rowIndex.username);
    navigate("/user/" + rowIndex.username, [navigate]);
  };

  const handleRemoveClick = (e, rowIndex) => {
    // console.log([rowIndex]);
    setShowModal(true);

    setModalMessage({
      title: `Remove ${rowIndex.username}`,
      message: `User's email to remove ${rowIndex.email}`,
    });
    setRemoveUserId(rowIndex.id);
  };

  const closeHandler = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    // console.log(removeUserId);
    setIda(removeUserId);
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  // console.log(ida, idb);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {showModal && (
        <BtModal
          show={showModal}
          title={modalMessage.title}
          message={modalMessage.message}
          handleClose={closeHandler}
          onConfirm={deleteHandler}
        />
      )}
      <Body>
        <h1>User Table</h1>

        {userData === undefined ? (
          <Spinner animation="border" />
        ) : (
          <>
            {userData === null ? (
              <p>Could not retrieve users.</p>
            ) : userData.length === 0 ? (
              <p>There are not users in system</p>
            ) : (
              <UserListTable
                newData={userData}
                handleEditClick={handleEditClick}
                handleRemoveClick={handleRemoveClick}
              />
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </Body>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

`useEffect` updated with `reload state`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await api.get("/admin/users");
      if (response.ok) {
        setUserData(response.body);
        effectRan.current = false;
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
      }
    })();
  }, [api, reload]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (effectRan.current) {
      // console.log("effect run");

      (async () => {
        const response = await api.delete("/admin/users", {
          ida: ida,
        });
        if (response.ok && response.status === 204) {
          console.log(response);
          setReload(!reload);
        } else {
          console.log(response.body.errors);
        }
      })();
    }
    return () => (effectRan.current = true);
  }, [api, ida, reload]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you modify your last edit

```
 const deleteHandler = () => {
    // console.log(removeUserId);
    setIda(removeUserId);
    setReload(!reload)
    setShowModal(false);
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await api.get("/admin/users");
      if (response.ok) {
        setUserData(response.body);
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
      }
    })();
  }, [api]);


  useEffect(() => {
     effectRan.current = reload;
    if (effectRan.current) {
      // console.log("effect run");

      (async () => {
        const response = await api.delete("/admin/users", {
          ida: ida,
        });
        if (response.ok && response.status === 204) {
          console.log(response);
          setReload(!reload);
        } else {
          console.log(response.body.errors);
        }
      })();
    }
    return () => {
         effectRan.current = false;
        };
  }, [api, ida, reload]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to delete an item in the table and confirm it via a prompt. I can see that you've used a lot of useEffects, which might be making things a bit complicated.

Don't worry though, I have a solution that should be much simpler. Let me show you what I mean!

```js
const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState([]);
  const [deleting, setDeleting] = useState(false);
  
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  const deleteHandler = async() => {
    setDeleting(true);
    await api.delete(selectedItem);

    // Next you can either update the state itself
    let tD = [...data];
    const index = tD.findIndex((i) => i.id == selectedItem);
    tD.splice(index, 1);
    setSelectedItem(tD);

    // or refetch data from the backend and update the state
    const d = await api.getData();
    setData(d);
    setDeleting(false);
    setSelectedItem(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      setLoading(true);
      const d = await api.getData();
      setData(d);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <>
    {/*Other JSX elements*/}

    {selectedItem && <div>

      {/*prompt body*/}

      <button onClick={() => {setSelectedItem(null)}}>Cancel</button>
      <button disabled={deleting} onClick={() => {deleteHandler()}}>Delete</button>
      {/*Button will be disabled when the DELETE request is sent*/}
    </div>}

    {data.map((row) => {
      return <tr key={row.id}>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={setSelectedItem(row.id)}>Delete</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
    })}
  </>
}
```